# Mysql LIMIT returning unexpected rows

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM users
ORDER BY highscore DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM users
ORDER BY highscore DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10
```

returning the same result. And they are different than the records when I omit the LIMIT clause! I searched the community. There are similar questions, but they are of no help.

EDIT: Here are the table data-

[image: Here is the table data ordered by <code>highscore</code>]

Comment: Is there any restriction to prevent users from having the same highscore?

Comment: No restrictions. I should also mention that many of them have the same high score.

Comment: show us table data

Comment: Please check the result of `SELECT *
FROM users
ORDER BY highscore DESC
LIMIT 15`. It's possible that values are same.

Comment: Keyur Panchal. Yes, the high score values are the same for them. They are all 0.

Comment: Then, unless `LIMIT 5` displays more than 5 rows, the results are probably correct. MySQL will just fetch rows that match your criteria.

Comment: Strange! How can I get the rows serially ordered by high score (5 rows at one page) then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, the issue is that you have ties for `highscore`.  When you have ties, then MySQL orders the rows with the same value in an arbitrary and indeterminate way.  Even two runs of the same query can result in different orderings.

Why?  The reason is simple.  There is no "natural" order for sorting keys with the same value.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

To make the sorting stable, include a unique id as the last key in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
ORDER BY u.highscore DESC, u.userId
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5;
```

Then, when you fetch the next 5 rows, they will be different.